# Adding attributes to an row count

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

> **OrderHasItem**
>
> - OrderTable_idOrder
> - Item_idItem
> - quantity

```
 SELECT Item_idItem, COUNT(Item_idItem)+quantity 
 FROM OrderHasItem
 GROUP BY Item_idItem
```

I want to count how many of each item, but also take into account the quantity of each entry.

The problem is when I tried it with this data I got really strange results:

**Data:**

> **OrderTable_idOrder**,   **Item_idItem**,    **quantity**
>
> 1,    1,  1
>
> 2,    1,  2
>
> 34,   4,  2
>
> 43,   4,  1
>
> 77,   2,  1

**Result:**

> **Item_idItem**,  **COUNT(Item_idItem)+quantity**
>
> 1,    3
>
> 2,    2
>
> 4,    4

I don't really understand how it got what it gave me so I'm not quite sure how to proceed. Thank you for the help.

Here is the target Data:

> **Item_idItem**, **quantity**
>
> 1, 3
>
> 4, 3
>
> 2, 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Item_idItem, COUNT(Item_idItem), COUNT(Item_idItem)+SUM(quantity) 
 FROM OrderHasItem
 GROUP BY Item_idItem
```

I think it should work, if sum of quantity and number of items is required.

Or

```
 SELECT Item_idItem, SUM(quantity)
 FROM OrderHasItem
 GROUP BY Item_idItem
```

if only sum of quantity is required.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it still is not quite right.


`Item_idItem, COUNT(Item_idItem), COUNT(Item_idItem)+SUM(quantity)

1, 2, 5--

2, 1, 2--

4, 2, 5`

Comment: I believe this is the result, and the result you have posted is fine according to the query, because it adds both number of items and quantity of items, If you only want sum of quantities, then you can simply select SUM(quantity)

Comment: If you can tell, what exactly is the result that you want on this data, then it might help more to understand @SimonTheCat

Comment: I am looking for:

`Item, quantity 

1,3 -- 

4, 3 --

2, 1`

Comment: The third one got me what I need. Thank you very much. I don't know how I missed such a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because quantity is not part of the `GROUP BY` clause it can not be selected reliably. So MySQL is returning more or less *arbitrary* data.

**Zohaib** has a query that you should use. I wanted to provide the explanation.